# Terraform: The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to implement the VNET Integration for my azure app service slots. Here we are able to create multiple slots with the `for_each` and all the slots should integreate with the same Vnet/Subnet (vnet integration)

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_slot" "app_service_slot_template"   {
  for_each = {for sl in "${var.app_service_slots}" : sl.name => sl }
  
  app_service_name = "${var.mandatory_prefix}-${var.app_service_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${data.azurerm_app_service_plan.service_plan.id}"
  location = "${var.resource_location}"
  https_only = true

 
      
        
  name =  "${each.value["name"]}"
  
  dynamic "site_config" {
    for_each = "${var.site_config}"
    content {
      min_tls_version = lookup(site_config.value, "min_tls_version", null)
      python_version = lookup(site_config.value, "python_version", null)
      java_version = lookup(site_config.value, "java_version", null)
      always_on = lookup(site_config.value, "always_on", null)
      app_command_line = lookup(site_config.value, "app_command_line", null)
      dotnet_framework_version = lookup(site_config.value, "dotnet_framework_version", null)          
    }
  }
  
  dynamic "connection_string" {
    for_each =  "${each.value["connection_strings"]}"
    content {
      name = "${connection_string.value["name"]}"
      type = "${connection_string.value["type"]}"
      value = "${connection_string.value["value"]}"
    }
  }

  app_settings = "${merge(each.value["app_settings"], local.additional_app_settings)}"
}



  # Get the Id of the subnet
data "azurerm_subnet" "azurerm_subnet_template" {
  name                 = "${var.subnet_name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${var.virtual_network_name}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.vnet_resource_group_name}"
}

# Create Vnet Integration (which is failing The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.)
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot" {
  count = length("${var.app_service_slots}")

  app_service_id = "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template["${count.index}"].id}"
  subnet_id      = "${data.azurerm_subnet.azurerm_subnet_template.id}"
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template]
}
```

All the above working fine except the vnet integration, The error I'm getting is

> on .terraform/modules/app_service/main.tf line 239, in resource
> "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection"
> "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot":  239:   app_service_id =
> "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template["${count.index}"].id}"
> |----------------
> | azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template is object with 1 attribute "stage"
> | count.index is 0
>
> The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

Googling leads me to this github issue https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5675

Where there are lots of discussions reg its the terraform bug, Not sure Am I hitting this bug ? Please note that my terraform version is *v0.13.4*

If is it a bug with my terraform version, is there any workaround to this without upgrading the version ? because upgrading the tf version is a big process for us.

---

Update 1:

updated the for_each instead of count for Vnet Integration part

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot" {
  for_each = {for sl in "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template}" : sl.name => sl }
  //count = length("${var.app_service_slots}")

  //app_service_id = "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template["${count.index}"].id}"
  app_service_id = "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template.*.id}"
  subnet_id      = "${data.azurerm_subnet.azurerm_subnet_template.id}"
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template]
}
```

Now the Error coming as

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> on .terraform/modules/generic_app_service/main.tf line 240, in
> resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection"
> "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot":  240:   app_service_id =
> "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template.*.id}"
> |----------------
> | azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template is object with 1 attribute "stage"
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "app_service_id": string required.
>
> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on .terraform/modules/generic_app_service/main.tf line 240, in
> resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection"
> "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot":  240:   app_service_id =
> "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template.*.id}"
>
> This object does not have an attribute named "id".

---

Upate 2:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot" {
  for_each = {for sl in "${azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template}" : sl.name => sl }

  app_service_id = "${each.value.id}"
  subnet_id      = "${data.azurerm_subnet.azurerm_subnet_template.id}"
  depends_on = [azurerm_app_service_slot.app_service_slot_template]
}
```

This works perfectly on the Terraform plan, however during the apply it failed with the below error

> Error: Error parsing App Service Resource ID
>
> on .terraform/modules/generic_app_service/main.tf line 235, in
> resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection"
> "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot":  235: resource
> "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection"
> "azureapp_vnet_integration_for_slot" {

I can confirm from the plan output the app_service_id is getting the correct resource id for the azure slot but don't know why it is complaining about App Service Resource ID

Comment: `for_each` and `count` resource do not work well together for the obvious reason that one accesses by value, the other by index number. Both resources should be `for_each` or both should be `count`.

Comment: @luk2302 I tried to use for_each instead of count and getting a different error, updated in my OP

Comment: I should be `app_service_id = each.value.id`

Comment: @Marcin thanks the plan is *working fine* now. but getting an error on the apply, please see the update2 in my OP

Comment: Its better to make new qustion, rather then adding new issues to this one.

Comment: @Marcin sure please provide your answer I'll accept it

Comment: I think @luk2302 would be better to do it. He spotted the issue with mixing count and for_each.

Comment: @luk2302 could you please convert your comment as an answer, I'll accept that